# SQL add 2 hour to a column with type "date"

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a column with dates, in an `Select` statement, and i want to add 2 h to each row in this `Select`.

Any advice?

Comment: Seems you are asking about SQL, could you [edit] your post and tag the DBMS?

Comment: the DBMS I mentioned is something like 'SQL Server', 'MS SQL', 'Oracle', 'MySQL'... etc

Comment: Could you confirm you are using sql-server? From the comment you leave in Aravind's answer, it seems you are using Oracle

Comment: I use Oracle .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer using `interval` for this:

```
select deliverydate + interval '2' hour
from the_table;
```

The above is standard SQL and works well in Oracle.

More details in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221

Answer (score 2):

### MS Access Update Query:

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON t2.ID = Table1.ID 
SET Table1.DeliveryDate = DateAdd("h",2,[t2].[DeliveryDate]);
```

### Sql Server Update Query:

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON t2.ID = Table1.ID 
SET Table1.DeliveryDate = DateAdd("hh",2,[t2].[DeliveryDate]);
```

### MS Access Select Query:

```
SELECT DateAdd("h",2,Table1.DeliveryDate) AS NewDateTime
FROM Table1;
```

### Sql Server Select Query:

```
SELECT DateAdd("hh",2,Table1.DeliveryDate) AS NewDateTime
FROM Table1;
```

### Oracle Select Query:

```
SELECT (Table1.DeliveryDate + 2/24) AS NewDateTime
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: i don't want to update my table

Comment: See my updated answer. You just need to create a calculated column:  In this example : `DateAdd("hh",2,[OldDate]) AS NewDateTime`  `NewDateTime` is the field alias/name for a field that is 2 hours greater than the `[OldDate]` fields.  You may need to create some additional logic to handle Nulls.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, i get error , "DateAdd": invalid identifier

Comment: I didn't see that you are using Oracle.  I update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works also with your last query. But unfortunately i can't accept 2 answers

Comment: No worries.  Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE testtime (my_date datetime);
  INSERT INTo testtime VALUES (GETDATE());
```

this prints the actual date

```
  select * from testtime
```

this prints time + 2 hrs

```
  select DATEADD(HOUR, 2, my_date) from testtime
```

Comment: if I did that it will change the data in database, all I want is to add 2 H into `select`

Comment: yea that was a mistake. sorry for that. Please do refer that link for ur answer ...

Comment: "dateadd": invalid identifier

Comment: @Marius : try this out its working for me.

Comment: unfortunetly is not working for me, i don't know why...my column with dates is type `date` i can't make `datetime`

Comment: @Marius, you said the datatype is `date`, may I know why you need to add 2H? The result will always be `yyyy/mm/dd 02:00`?

Comment: into my `select` i add `to_char(time_from_UTC, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')` to show the datetime

Comment: yeah , that is a point.. change ur type to datetime from date. Try after that. Its working fine for me nyway..

Comment: I don't have acces to change the datebase.  Only i need to do is to work with `select`

Comment: @marius , can u tell me what is the problem with below code which suggested by  Aravind R Pillai ?  select DATEADD(HOUR, 2, my_date) from testtime

Comment: @Ronak Patel, "dateadd": invalid identifier

Comment: are u using MS SQL Server ?

Comment: @RonakPatel, check the new comment in question, he using oracle